# Xamarin.iOS bluetooth connectivity on iPad locked

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, core-bluetooth

My BLE device uses SSL certificate on connection which is causing the app to hang when the iPad gets locked. It works fine as long as I don't lock the iPad. anyone faced similar problem?

What I tried is to disconnect the device on sleep and reconnect it on resume. It works fine when the app goes into background and comes back, the problem comes when I lock the iPad and then resume to app. Same events fire whether I lock the device or minimize it.
Can anyone tell me how Xamarin handles these 2 things?

I have enabled background modes and tried everything available on the internet but I couldn't get it working.

It starts working when I kill the app and try to reconnect it.
How do I dispose the connection with my bluetooth device properly on sleep and then start as a new?

P.S I'm using dependency services in Xamarin.Forms.